# CSS, problem with transition and overflow

Tags: css, overflow, transition

I have a little problem with my code and can't figure how to fix it. I want images to appear in a box when I pass over a title (I don't know JS). I manage to do the main thing but the image appear out of the box, the overflow hidden don't work and the second title just appears under the box instead of right to it (under the other title). Here is my code

```css
.PAstaff {
  width: 560px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.BGstaff {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ZNxezg5.png);
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}

a.imginfo {
  position: relative;
  color: #949494;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.LKSstaff {
  color: #949494;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 275px;
  height: 25px;
}

a.imginfo span {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  width: 250px;
}

a.imginfo hover {
  background: none;
  z-index: 700;
}

a.imginfo:hover span {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 800;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  width: 250px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease 0.4s;
  margin-left: -350px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.ICNstaff {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -280px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="PAstaff">
  <div class="BGstaff">
    <a class="imginfo">
      <div class="LKSstaff">
        <b>STAFF1</b>
        <div class="ICNstaff"></div>
        <span>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Q4UL0Pm.png" width="300px" />
        </span>
      </div>
  </div>
  </a>
  <a class="imginfo">
    <div class="LKSstaff">
      <b>STAFF2</b>
      <span>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vfV96UV.png" width="300px" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

thank you and sorry for the bother !

I've tried putting the positions in absolute, changing the hierarchy and the transition method, when images are on `display: none`, everything works well, but I can't put any transition.

Comment: You want image to be appear inside left box, which has background image when on hovering buttons staff1 & staff2 ?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `transform` property will work better than changing the `margin` in most instances. See how Staff1 now functions with `transform` instead in the example. See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) for more info. In order to fix the overflow issue put the image inside the element that you want to contain it, like `<div class="ICNstaff"></div>`

```css
.PAstaff {
  width: 560px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.BGstaff {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ZNxezg5.png);
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}

a.imginfo {
  position: relative;
  color: #949494;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.LKSstaff {
  color: #949494;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 275px;
  height: 25px;
}

a.imginfo span {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  width: 250px;
}

a.imginfo hover {
  background: none;
  z-index: 700;
}

a.imginfo:hover span {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 800;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  width: 250px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease 0.4s;
  margin-left: -350px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.ICNstaff {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -280px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}


/* NEW CSS */
a.imginfo img.hoverImg {
  width: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.15s linear;
}
a.imginfo:hover img.hoverImg {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="PAstaff">
  <div class="BGstaff">
    <a class="imginfo">
      <div class="LKSstaff">
        <b>STAFF1</b>
        <div class="ICNstaff">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Q4UL0Pm.png" width="250" class="hoverImg" />
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </a>
  <a class="imginfo">
    <div class="LKSstaff">
      <b>STAFF2</b>
      <span>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vfV96UV.png" width="300px" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```